# Webdriver.io (wdio) - Browserstack - waitforDisplayed fails

Tags: node.js, wdio-v6, wdio-jasmine

I'm working on some tests with wdio 6 (on my way to upgrade it to 7) and I've been receiving this error on a very simple test

```
    it('Renders unit list', () => {
        $('.unit-list .bookable-unit-details:first-child').waitForDisplayed();
    });
```

While running the test I get this triggered a lot of times:

```
[0-0] 2021-07-14T20:20:56.077Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown command: POST /session/<HASH>/execute/sync
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '208-52-164-61', ip: '208.52.164.61', os.name: 'windows', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

And at the very end:

```
[chrome 91.0.4472.106 windows #0-0] Error: waitUntil condition failed with the following reason: POST /session/<HASH>/execute/sync
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '208-52-164-61', ip: '208.52.164.61', os.name: 'windows', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Has anyone experienced this before?
What was the solution?

**EDIT**

I've upgraded the wdio to the latest available and I'm still having this issue.

I've submitted an issue on wdio's github: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/7145

Comment: so.. this means your server isn't receiving the post requests then ;-; so the problem most likely is theirs AND they just close the problem.. OOF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received some help from the Browserstack support team.

They told me to add the following capabilities to my configuration:

```
'browserstack.selenium_version': '3.141.59',
'browserstack.use_w3c': true,
```

That helped me to solve the issue (at least for the moment).